# Relationship of SAP Fiori to SAP S/4HANA?

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-erp, s4hana

I'm a beginner and trying to learn SAP ERP and know that SAP S/4HANA is the new version. Is SAP Fiori a way to run S/4HANA? Doesn't SAP S/4HANA already have a presentation layer in its 3-layer system?

I've read that SAP Fiori is for UX and a bit more deeply on the 3-layer system of SAP S/4HANA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP traditionally used proprietary graphical user interface technology called **SAP-GUI**. Interface is developed in own programming language `ABAP`, screens in accordance with the technology are called classical screens `Dynpros` and communicate with SAP application server using own protocol. First it required installation of the local client and later SAP has introduced also `Web Dynpro` technology which could be employed to render the classical GUI-screens on the web-interface, what actually is only a transformation of display surface.

As a result of complete re-thinking and technological transformation SAP has developed a completely new way of interaction with enterprise applications and a new user interface called **Fiori**. Fiori has renewed the most widely-used scenarios and is aimed at keeping things simple. Frontend part is based of the web-technology using `HTML5` and own `JavaScript` UI library `SAPUI5`. This is a SAP's user experience that applies modern usercentric design principles. So actually Fiori can be thought of as a design guidelines for an SAP web applications.

These both frontend technologies can be used and are used with classic R3 ERP system and with SAP S/4HANA. It is possible to run R3 system with HANA used as a database. SAP S/4HANA is a new platform with re-engineered applications, simplified database model, IoT, Big data, predictive analysis and many other possibilities. Main frontend technology and focus is on UI5 (Fiori), but it also works with a classic GUI.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexSchell for your lucid answer.